# How to only select row if table timestamp has been updated

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

Currently im selecting most updated row using the following php block, i have an ajax loop which runs this php block every few seconds to return feed. i want to echo false to ajax when latest timestamp hasn't changed so that ajax doesn't duplicate results and fill my Div (#feed) with identical content.

```
<?php 
require_once 'db_conx.php';
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles ORDER BY lastupdated desc limit 1") or die   (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
echo $row['name'];
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I would store the last timestamp that returned a result in the client/session/etc. and then when the AJAX call triggers send the last time stamp along for comparison purposes.  If it hasn't changed, return false.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in the session, or in the requestor, you need to store the last fetched time. It would be better to store it as a session variable (this I presume is client-specific because different clients will have loaded at different times) and then fetch all records that have their `lastupdated` time greater than the `last_fetched` time.

Everytime entries are fetched from the DB, just update the `last_fetched` variable to the current timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this every 5 seconds, I would do something like

```
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE lastupdated >  ADDTIME( NOW( ) ,  '-00:00:05.00000' ) ORDER BY lastupdated desc limit 1") or die   (mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows = 0)  {
   return false;
} else {
   return true;
}
```

This will give you any rows that have been updated in the last 5 seconds, if it is older than this it should have been picked up in the last run.

Hope this helps

Comment: Seems viable, and how do u intend to reply to ajax that there's no new content?

Comment: Modified my answer, if not exactly that then something similar should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve your results from the server I'm guessing you store the timestamp of the last query in some PHP variable in order to compare the returned results of the next query.
I would concatenate the timestamp into your query as a where clause so your sql query would become something like

```
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE lastupdated > " . $timestamp . " ORDER BY lastupdated desc limit 1") or die   (mysql_error());
```

It's also worth noting that when this executes if there has been more than one profile updated since the last update cycle then it will only return the most recently updated row.
Does this answer your question?

Comment: No, variable storage and comparison is what I haven't got to, I'm not storing it. That's what I wanna know how to do.